# What is the replacement for the Datastore Admin for GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I keep seeing errors in the Dev Server console log about the Datastore Admin builtin being deprecated.  Is just the builtin deprecated or is the whole Datastore Admin deprecated.  If the latter, what is the replacement.

> WARNING  2012-03-26 15:04:34,698 appinfo.py:676] The datastore_admin builtin is deprecated.

Bonus points: why does DS Admin only work in Firefox?

Thanks,
Kurt

Comment: What do you want to use the datastore admin for? Most of its functionality is now available in the regular admin console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the DS Admin on/off from the Admin Console, you don't need to specify in app.yaml anymore.

DS Admin works fine for me in Chrome.  Where is it not working for you?

Comment: When I click on the link "Datastore Admin" from the App Engine Console, the iframe fails to load.  Looking at the source it says that my browser doesn't support frames (which is weird since I'm using the latest version of Chrome)

Comment: I take that back.  It's broken for me too.  You're right.  It was working previously, and I do see an error in the Chrome debugger saying "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."  Looks like a bug.

Comment: I can access it if I use Incognito mode... if you're logged into multiple Google accounts at the same time, might cause this.